# How to send file to remote computer?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i can get file name via below codes. How can i send this file to remote computer. this remote computer ip: 192.168.2.105 also i can use 51124 port

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] dosyalarinYollari = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"z:\20071008\1.2.392.200036.9116.2.6.1.48.1215563310.1191800303.305777\", "*.dcm", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (string s in dosyalarinYollari)
            {
                Console.Write(s+"\n");  // i need to send tihs s file to remote machine
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

There isn't nearly enough information here to give you a definitive answer, but I can mention some approaches. There are many ways to transfer files between computers, each with pros and cons.

- Windows file sharing. As mentined by GxG, if this is a Windows (or SMB) environment, and you had the necessary permissions, and file sharing was enabled, you could try `\\ipaddress\share\filename.`
- If the remote machine is across the internet, or file sharing is not available, protocols such as FTP are designed for uploading files to a remote machine, but the remote machine will need to be running an FTP server. .Net has native support for FTP (since .Net 2.0)
- You could roll your own listener that listens for connections on the target machine, and receives the binary file stream and writes it to disk.
- If you can connect to the remote machine via SSH, you could look at making a SCP call to upload the file
- If this is an environment with NFS shares (.e.g the remote machine is possibly a UNIX server) you could mount in NFS and copy.

Some solutions are easier than others. Some require the target machine to be running a server. Some are Windows only, Unix only, etc, etc.

Can you give us more information on your environment, why you need to do this, etc.

Comment: judging by the ip he wants to send it via a intranet connection and judging by the code he is using C# forms therefore is a Windows env.
FTP is also available on the intranet but it is far more complicated, and SSH is a good choice if security is an issue.
For Win to Unix i would use SSH, but i think my approach would work also(never tried it but in theory everything is done on the Transport Layer of the network therefore the OS wouldn't be an issue)

Comment: @GxG: Actually the IP address seems to belong to a LAN. 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 is reserved for local area networks.

Comment: intranet = inside a network
usually made using a router => the ips 192.168.xxx.xxx which come by default on most routers, or using a switch in which case the ips would be(by default) 10.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: @GxG - You are probably right about the intranet, but I can't be sure. If I ever post a question (or answer) containing IP addresses, the first thing I do is anonymise the IP addresses by putting them on 192.168.0.0/24 or somesuch.

Comment: hahaha... that's a sneaky way of doing it... but also is misleading...
i would just put it as [someIP] not give an actual IP... or say if it's an intranet IP or an internet IP...

Answer (score 1):

a simple File.Copy passing the location as @"\[ip][drive]$[folder]" is enough to send it to a remote computer if you have rights to log on to that computer.

i'm not really sure about the location string.

Comment: Doesn't this require file and printer sharing to be installed and the drive to be shared properly?

Comment: @Adrian Grigore: Yes, it does, but the OP didn't tell what protocol to use. @GxG: You are missing some backslashes in your path, and using an administrative share like `c$` requires administrative permissions on the remote host.

Comment: if you are logged in as Administrator you can transfer without a problem if you are the Admin on all computers. If you are using network log-on again it isn't that much of a problem, but you could encounter a log-on error. There is no solution for this, just a workaround: before the transfer run a Process.Start with this command: net use \\machinenameorip\driveletter$ /user:domain\username password

Comment: @0xA3 sorry about that \\ip\drive$\folder
to copy on the root does not require administrative privileges, just read/write privileges.

Comment: @GxG: No, this is not correct. Accessing an administrative share (i.e. any drive letter + `$` or `admin$`) requires the user to be a member of the local (i.e. on the remote system) Administrators group. Be careful not to confuse these built-in administrative shares with a *hidden* share (i.e. any other share with a name ending in $).